# Batch- issue with changing variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm making a video game in Batch and need a cheat code system. My code is here:

```
:Cheats
cls
echo Enter a valid cheat code.
echo Type back to return home.
echo.
set /p pass="Enter:"
if %pass%==back goto Home
if %pass%==gimmedaloot set /a gld=%gld%+1000 && set %name%=Cheater
if %pass%==iamironman set /a hp=%hp%+100 && set %name%=Cheater
if %pass%==thatsitiquit goto End && set %name%=Cheater
if %pass%==duncanwashere goto Debug && set %name%=Cheater
pause
goto Home
```

The issue is that it will not set the %name% variable to Cheater. It just leaves it as it was before. Help?

Comment: use `set name` instead. `%name%` is the value of the variable `name`, you can't set it. It would be the same as doing `set 5=3`

Comment: @Ploutox: surprise! `set 5=3` works well with batch ^^ - besides that, you are right. Also a single `&` will do. I would suggest to write `set "%name%=Cheater" & goto ...`